# PCRE regex for single capture group on string missing delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I have html with this sort of node value:

```
80% Polyester 10% Cotton 10% Rayon
```

It can also be like these:

```
90% Cotton 10% Rayon
```

Or:

```
100% Cotton
```

**EDIT -- ALSO** the text to capture might be more than one word like:

```
90% Egyptian Cotton 10% Polyester
```

What I need to do in PHP is change it to be like:

```
<li>80% Polyester</li>
<li>10% Cotton</li>
<li>10% Rayon</li>
```

I'm not sure how to get the capture group quite right... maybe there needs to be two capture groups that can happen 1+ times?

```
preg_match('/<p>([1-9]?[0-9]?% [^\d<]+|^100% )+<\/p>/', '<p>80% Polyester 10% Cotton 10% Rayon</p>', $matches);
```

This only finds 1 match for: 10% Rayon... what am I doing wrong for it not to capture all 3 groups?

**EDIT:  PLEASE FORGET ABOUT THE HTML TAGS**

I stripped the tags from the question because people can't get over the whole regex and html issue... think of this as just a data string please.

Comment: This should be done through the DOM and not regex.

Comment: preg_match_all doesn't return the other 2 results... please no answers about simple dom or other dom related answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `preg_replace`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/([\d.]+%\h*\pL+(?:\h+\pL+)*)\h*/', 
                     '<li>$1</li>\n', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i2gk5q/3)

`([\d.]+%\h*\pL+(?:\h+\pL+)*)\h*` matches and groups 1+ digits followed by `%` followed by 0+ spaces followed by 1+ letter and space characters.

Comment: I'll update the question, but this will not work if the material is more than 1 word... like 70% Egyptian Cotton

Comment: Checks out. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first enter the delimited structure, then you can use a regex on the newly found string. This can be done with `preg_replace_callback`.

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/', function($match) {
    if(preg_match_all('/\d+%\h+\D+/', $match[1], $newmatch)) {
        $temp = '';
        foreach($newmatch[0] as $li) {
            $temp .= '<li>' . $li . '</li>';
        }
        return $temp;
    }
}, '<p>80% Polyester 10% Cotton 10% Rayon</p>');
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/rQKL5

You also might want to change the `\D+` to something like `[a-zA-Z]+` or something else depending on what the label of the percentage units can be.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your string then I don't understand why you need regex at all.
You can use explode to make it an array and foreach loop it with array_chunk to get two items at the time (percentage and material).

```
$str = "80% Polyester 10% Cotton 10% Rayon";

Foreach(array_chunk(explode(" ", $str),2) as $material){
    Echo "<li>" . Implode(" ", $material) . "</li>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<li>80% Polyester</li>
<li>10% Cotton</li>
<li>10% Rayon</li>
```

https://3v4l.org/pE9NI

Comment: because the 'material' might be 2 words or more and therefore the ,2 in your array_chunk will not work.